# Unity build game has a different game view than in editor

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've been following after a course to learn Unity. Everything is working inside the editor, but when building the game, the game area that player sees is different than what is set in Unity editor.

[image]

The aspect ratio is set to 9:16 and I've tried to set the default screen resolution to those aspects, like 1080 for width and 1920 for height. But as you can see, the red line is what should be the edge of the screen (in unity editor, that is indeed the edge of the screen) but in build game it is not. Player is not supposed to see any of the black background.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It's an easy fix - just go to the game view, and in the top left there your aspect ratio, For now it's probably "Free Aspect", just press on the down arrow to the right of it and press that little plus button and add your own aspect ratio!

Good luck with your game!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qj4CK.png)

Comment: Its not on free aspect. As I said, my game has an aspect ratio of 9:16. The built game has a vertical game view, but player sees more than they should.